# Display images with PictureBox in c#

Tags: c#

I have write below codes in c# to display an image in `PictureBox` but when run the application, nothing shown...

Please help me to fix that.

here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox p =new PictureBox();
        p.ImageLocation = "1.jpg"
        p.Location = new Point(100, 75);
    }
```

Comment: You create a PictureBox but where do you place it on the form? Also, you set ImageLocation to a filename without the path. How did you determine that it's looking in the right directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this line:

```
  this.Controls.Add(p);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
PictureBox.Image = new Bitmap("yourImage.jpg");
```

The formats supported
are: `BMP, EMF, EXIF, GIF, ICON, JPEG, PNG, TIFF and WMF.`

Comment: I guess that might make the OP's code a little bit shorter, but it doesn't actually solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the PictureBox size is small and your image is too big (check the SizeMode property to "StrechImage")
I was using a high res PNG icon with transparent background and took a little time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task<PictureBox> CargarImagenDesdeUnDirectorioAsync()
    {
PictureBox pbImage
        try
        {
            openFileDialog.Title = "Open Image";
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Imagen (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Imagen (*.png)|*.png";
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // pbImage.ImageLocation = openFileDialog.FileName;
                pbImage.Image = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
                
                await Task.Delay(200);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al cargar la imagen, mensaje del error: " + e.Message);
        }
        return pbImage;
    }
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76229482/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).